# Sealant plus wax, or just sealant?

Tags: paint, detailing

I was reading in [The Haynes Automotive Body Repair & Painting Manual ( 1989 )](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1850104794) that after polishing, you can put a sealant on before you wax in order to give better, longer lasting protection to the paint.

However, when looking at sealants [from a variety of manufacturers](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_shipping_option-_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A15684181%2Ck%3Acar%20paint%20sealant%20-polish%2Cp_n_shipping_option-bin%3A3242350011&keywords=car%20paint%20sealant%20-polish&ie=UTF8&qid=1468745193&rnid=2944662011) like Chemical Guys, Wolfgang, McGuiar's, etc... I get the impression that they are meant to be used *in place of* wax and not as an additional layer in between the clear coat and wax.

Which one is correct?  Has the technology and practice simply changed since the book was published in '89?

Comment: I think the times have changed dramatically between 1989 and now, especially with sealants. I don't have any kind of background on it, but looking at a few web pages, it seems it's one or the other. Sealant will repel water and debris, but sits on top of the clear coat. It lasts longer, like 4-6 months. Carnauba wax looks like it melts into the paint (it really doesn't, but looks that way), so has a much better look to it. You can layer it on for it to look deeper. It only lasts 4-6 weeks, though.

Comment: Most sealants do *allow* for waxing after sealing, but purely for cosmetic reasons, as many people prefer the "glow" of wax over just sealant.